# Overriding property accessor names in Objective-C with @synthesize

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to find documentation on how I can override a property name in Objective-C with @synthesize. If I have an instance variable name of 'foo', I want to write it's accessor as 'bar'.

Doing something such as

```
@synthesize foo = bar;
```

gives a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but "bar" has to exist first (be a declared variable). From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_5_section_3.html)

> You can use the form property=ivar to indicate that a particular instance variable should be used for the property, for example:

```
@synthesize firstName, lastName, age = yearsOld;
```

Comment: In the OP's example, the correct form would be @synthesize bar = foo; since he says foo is his ivar and he wants to access it with bar.

Answer (score 13):

I think you just have it backwards in your @synthesize.  What you want is:

```
@synthesize bar = foo;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change the getter name when you declare the property (getter=bar).