# What is this @synthesize statment doing? 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

Given the following class def:

```
@interface MyController : OtherController {
    NSString *_ID;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *ID;
@end
```

and the following implementation:

```
@implementation DRMControllerNDS
@synthesize ID =_ID;
@end
```

What is the `@synthesize` statement doing here? Specifically why are we are setting the `_ID` instance variable value to the `ID` property? Isn't `_ID` going to be `nil` at this point in execution? I have seen this construct used many times and am yet to understand its purpose...

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It's a convention to distinguish between direct access to the variable (_var), and access through the synthesized accessors (self.var).

Comment: Similar questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802851/objective-c-synthesize-property-name-overriding), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277209/can-someone-explain-this-synthesize-syntax), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112283/question-about-synthesize/6112553), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802851), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382051), [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266467), [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631), [8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277209), [9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719788)

Comment: @Sabobin: Each of those numbers is a link.

Comment: Oh, my mistake sorry guys. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain English, the @synthesize line says "Create the getter and setter methods for the property "ID", but don't use an instance variable called "ID" (the default) to store the value, use an instance variable called "_ID" instead."

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to access `instanceOfMyController._ID`, you'll get an error because the `._ID` property doesn't exist; the `@synthesize` directive allows you to use the dot notation.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802851/objective-c-synthesize-property-name-overriding) for more.

Comment: The `_ID` property still doesn't exist; no such property has been declared. The property is `ID`, and this `@synthesize` directive tells the compiler to use the `_ID` instance variable for the `ID` property's storage.

Comment: So is the goal to allow you to use the dot notation or use the instance variable name, but keep them separate for some reason? It's still not clear. In other words, can I write: instanceOfMyController.ID OR _ID to access the variable? Or am I restricted to one or the other?

Comment: Oh, just thought of something: is using _ID a way to get around using getters and setters? That is, if I use instanceOfMyController.ID I am using the setter/getter, but if I use _ID, I'm not?